# How to format & design the JSON format in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a request to make the below JSON format and it seems very complex to me, I tried with the below solution but facing 2 issues

1.Sub child items  under the child items seems not to be working.

2. Also if i have multiple products in one order , I would like to have that comes under this tags "lineItems" , But instead with the solution i have worked upon, If there are multiple products each is generating a separate JSON row, I need one JSON row per order.

It will be of very help if anyone of can give shred some light here.

Sample JSON String to be constructed.

```
{
  "order_id": "string",
  "createdAt": 0,
  "orderNumber": "string", 
  "tags": [
    "string"
  ],
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "line_id": "string",
      "productName": "string",
      "quantity": 0, 
      "productTags": [ 
        "string"
      ],
      "discounts": [
        {
          "title": "string", 
          "voucherCode": "string", 
          "discountAmount": 0.1 
        }
      ],
      "taxes": [
        {
          "tactitle": "string",
          "taxRate": 0.1,
          "taxAmount": 0.1
        }
      ],
      "totalAmountBeforeTaxesAndDiscounts": 0.1,
      "totalAmountAfterTaxesAndDiscounts": 0.1
    }
  ],
  "shipping": {
    "city": "string",
    "zipOrPostalCode": "string",
    "providerDescriptor": "string", 
    "shippingTotalAmountBeforeTaxAndDiscounts": 0.1,
    "discounts": [
      {
        "title": "string",
        "voucherCode": "string",
        "discountAmount": 0.1
      }
    ],
    "taxes": [
      {
        "title": "string",
        "taxRate": 0.1,
        "taxAmount": 0.1
      }
    ],
    "shippingTotalAmountAfterTaxAndDiscounts": 0.1
  },
  "transactionCosts": 0.1,
  "customer": {
    "id": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "tags": [ 
      "string"
    ]
  },
  "optional": {
    "googleAnalyticsTransactionId": "string",
    "orderSourceName": "string",
    "orderChannelName": "string",
    "orderPlatformName": "string"
  }
}
```

The solution I have tried is below.

```
With  orders as
(
SELECT "order_id",
      "createdAt",
      "orderNumber", 
      STRING_AGG(tags,',') as tags
FROM  orders o
        )
,lineItems as
(
SELECT   "line_id",
          order_id
          "productName",
          "quantity", 
          STRING_AGG(productTags,',') as "productTags",
          "vouchertitle", 
          "voucherCode",
          "discountAmount",
          "taxtitle",
          "taxRate",
          "taxAmount",
          "totalAmountBeforeTaxesAndDiscounts",
          "totalAmountAfterTaxesAndDiscounts"
FROM items 
)
,shipments as
(
SELECT  order_id,
        "city",
        "zipOrPostalCode",
        "providerDescriptor", 
        "shippingTotalAmountBeforeTaxAndDiscounts",
        "title",
        "voucherCode",
        "discountAmount", 
        "taxtitle",
        "taxRate",
        "taxAmount",
        "shippingTotalAmountAfterTaxAndDiscounts"
FROM shipments s
INNER JOIN orders o ON s.order_id=o.id
)
,customer AS
(
SELECT 
        order_id,
        "customer_id",
        "email"
         STRING_AGG("customer_tags") as tags
FROM  customers c 
)
, optional AS
(
SELECT  order_id,
        "googleAnalyticsTransactionId",
        "source",
        "channel",
        "platform"
    FROM analytics
)
   , base as (
  select   
          cm.*,i as lineItems 
          , s as shipment
          , c as customer
          , ga as  "optionalIdentifiers"
  from 
    orders cm
    LEFT JOIN lineItems i ON  cm.order_id = i.order_id 
    LEFT JOIN shipments s ON cm.order_id=s.order_id
    LEFT JOIN customer c ON cm."order_id"=c.order_id
    LEFT JOIN optional ga ON cm."order_id"=ga.order_id     
 )
 select row_to_json(c) as "data" from base c
```

Sample Input

```
create temp table orders(order_id int,"createdAt" date,"orderNumber" text,tags text);
INSERT INTO orders(order_id,"createdAt","orderNumber",tags)
VALUES (1,'2022-12-09' , '10001', 'no tags'),
       (2,'2022-12-10' , '19999', 'tag1,tags 2');
 
create temp table lineItems(line_id int,order_id int,"productName" text,"quantity" int,
 "productTags" text,"vouchertitle" text,"voucherCode" text,"discountAmount" real,
"taxtitle" text,"taxRate" real,"taxAmount" real,"totalAmountBeforeTaxesAndDiscounts" real,
"totalAmountAfterTaxesAndDiscounts" real);
INSERT INTO lineItems(line_id ,order_id ,"productName" ,"quantity" ,
 "productTags" ,"vouchertitle" ,"voucherCode" ,"discountAmount" ,
"taxtitle" ,"taxRate" ,"taxAmount" ,"totalAmountBeforeTaxesAndDiscounts" ,
"totalAmountAfterTaxesAndDiscounts" )
VALUES (0,1,'Vitamin D',100,'Bio','Xmas campaign','XMAS001',1000,'TAX 10%',10,500,15000,14000),
       (2,1,'Vitamin C',50,'No Tags','Xmas campaign','XMAS001',500,'TAX 7%',7,33,1900,1400),
       (11,2,'Vitamin C',50,'No Tags','Xmas campaign','XMAS002',100,'TAX 7%',7,55,2500,2400)
;

create temp table shipments(order_id int,"city" text,"zipOrPostalCode" text,"providerDescriptor" text, 
"shippingTotalAmountBeforeTaxAndDiscounts" real,"title" text,"voucherCode" text,"discountAmount" real, 
"taxtitle" text,"taxRate" real,"taxAmount" real,"shippingTotalAmountAfterTaxAndDiscounts" real);
INSERT INTO shipments(order_id ,"city" ,"zipOrPostalCode" ,"providerDescriptor" , 
"shippingTotalAmountBeforeTaxAndDiscounts" ,"title" ,"voucherCode" ,"discountAmount" , 
"taxtitle" ,"taxRate" ,"taxAmount" ,"shippingTotalAmountAfterTaxAndDiscounts" )
VALUES (1,'Berlin','100203','DHL','100','Shipper','XMAS001',1000,'TAX 10%',10,500,1000),
  (2,'Milan','122203','Hermes','100','Shipp_001','XMAS002',1000,'TAX 7%',7,500,1000);

create temp table customer(  order_id int,"customer_id" int,"email" text,"customer_tags" text);
INSERT INTO customer(order_id ,"customer_id" ,"email" ,"customer_tags" )
VALUES (1,1900,'xxxx@gmail.com','new')
,      (2,2000,'yyyy@gmail.com','return');


create temp table optional( order_id int,"googleAnalyticsTransactionId" int,"source" text,"channel" text,"platform" text);
INSERT INTO optional(order_id ,"googleAnalyticsTransactionId" ,"source" ,"channel" ,platform)
VALUES (1,'9990001','facebook','paid marketing','mobile')
      ,(2,'7770001','gppgle','direct','mobile');
```

Sample Expected Output
The output JSON is formulated with only one entry,With order id=1

```
 {
      "order_id": "1",
      "createdAt": "2022-12-09",
      "orderNumber": '10001', 
      "tags": ['no tags' ],
      "lineItems": [
        {
          "line_id": "0",
          "productName": 'Vitamin D',
          "quantity": 100, 
          "productTags": [ 'Bio'],
          "discounts": [
            {
              "title": 'Xmas campaign', 
              "voucherCode": 'XMAS001', 
              "discountAmount": 1000 
            }
          ],
          "taxes": [
            {
              "tactitle": 'TAX 10%',
              "taxRate": 10,
              "taxAmount": 500
            }
          ],  
          "totalAmountBeforeTaxesAndDiscounts": 15000,
          "totalAmountAfterTaxesAndDiscounts": 14000
        },
          {
          "line_id": "2",
          "productName": 'Vitamin C',
          "quantity": 50, 
          "productTags": [ 'No Tags'],
          "discounts": [
            {
              "title": 'Xmas campaign', 
              "voucherCode": 'XMAS001', 
              "discountAmount": 500 
            }
          ],
          "taxes": [
            {
              "tactitle": 'TAX 7%',
              "taxRate": 7,
              "taxAmount": 33
            }
          ],  
          "totalAmountBeforeTaxesAndDiscounts": 1900,
          "totalAmountAfterTaxesAndDiscounts": 1400
        }
      ],
      "shipping": {
        "city": 'Berlin',
        "zipOrPostalCode": "100203",
        "providerDescriptor": "DHL", 
        "shippingTotalAmountBeforeTaxAndDiscounts": 100,
        "discounts": [
          {
            "title": "TAX 10%",
            "voucherCode": 'XMAS001',
            "discountAmount": 500
          }
        ],
        "taxes": [
          {
            "title": "XMAS001",
            "taxRate": 10,
            "taxAmount": 500
          }
        ],
        "shippingTotalAmountAfterTaxAndDiscounts": 1000
      },
      "transactionCosts": 0.1,
      "customer": {
        "id": "1900",
        "email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
        "tags": [ 
          "new"
        ]
       },
      "optional": {
        "googleAnalyticsTransactionId": "9990001",
        "orderSourceName": "facebook",
        "orderChannelName": "paid marketing",
        "orderPlatformName": "mobile"
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you share sample input tables for this task and expected output matching the input sample?

Comment: @lemon Added the detials.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a part for you, which by looking at the code, you can understand how the functions work. I think you can write the continuation of the same by looking at this logic. If you have a problem, you can tell me, I will write it in full, I just didn't write all the names of the fields, so I'm sorry.

SQL query:

```
select  json_build_object('lineItems', 
            json_agg(json_build_object(
                'line_id', lt.line_id, 
                'productName', lt."productName", 
                'quantity', lt.quantity, 
                'discounts', 
                    json_build_array(json_build_object(
                        'title', lt.vouchertitle, 
                        'voucherCode', lt."voucherCode", 
                        'discountAmount', lt."discountAmount")), 
                'taxes', 
                    json_build_array(json_build_object(
                        'tactitle', lt.taxtitle, 
                        'taxRate', lt."taxRate", 
                        'taxAmount', lt."taxAmount")), 
                'totalAmountBeforeTaxesAndDiscounts', lt."totalAmountBeforeTaxesAndDiscounts", 
                'totalAmountAfterTaxesAndDiscounts', lt."totalAmountAfterTaxesAndDiscounts")) 
        ) 
from orders o 
inner join lineitems lt on o.order_id = lt.order_id 
inner join shipments sp on o.order_id = sp.order_id 
where o.order_id = 1
```

And result:

```
{
    "lineItems": [
        {
            "line_id": 0,
            "productName": "Vitamin D",
            "quantity": 100,
            "discounts": [
                {
                    "title": "Xmas campaign",
                    "voucherCode": "XMAS001",
                    "discountAmount": 1000
                }
            ],
            "taxes": [
                {
                    "tactitle": "TAX 10%",
                    "taxRate": 10,
                    "taxAmount": 500
                }
            ],
            "totalAmountBeforeTaxesAndDiscounts": 15000,
            "totalAmountAfterTaxesAndDiscounts": 14000
        },
        {
            "line_id": 2,
            "productName": "Vitamin C",
            "quantity": 50,
            "discounts": [
                {
                    "title": "Xmas campaign",
                    "voucherCode": "XMAS001",
                    "discountAmount": 500
                }
            ],
            "taxes": [
                {
                    "tactitle": "TAX 7%",
                    "taxRate": 7,
                    "taxAmount": 33
                }
            ],
            "totalAmountBeforeTaxesAndDiscounts": 1900,
            "totalAmountAfterTaxesAndDiscounts": 1400
        }
    ]
}
```